# Reading Python Module from different PATH

Tags: python, path, environment, python-import

I have a directory layout like this:

```
Pytest\
  __init__.py
  connect.py
  sql.py
  test.py
```

what I want to do is that Pytest directory would be in my python environment path so that I can import all the modules i.e. connect.py, sql.py or test.py anywhere outside this directory or even the interactive shell.

This is what I have in my `__init__.py`:

```
from .connect import *
from .sql import *
from .test import *
```

for this I think I the parent directory should be in python path. The question is how should I go about it?

Comment: Is your question about how to add the above path in the environment variables (PATH) programmatically? or would it be okay to do  command line (or other methods)

Comment: @AnandSKumar I would like to know both ways if its possible. also I was thinking if there's a way to know to make that happen through `__init__.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting the Python path from inside a python script, you can use the `sys.path.append()` method, this method takes the directory as string which you need to add to the python path.

Example -

```
import sys
sys.path.append(dir)
```

Where `dir` is the directory you want to add to the path , after this any files within the dir file can be imported without issues.

To set the python to take python files from a different directory directly through the terminal or other means, you need to set the `PYTHONPATH` variable, and not the `PATH` variable (`PATH` variable is used by the system to find executables, its not used by Python to find modules/python files) .

**PYTHONPATH** - This variable tells the Python interpreter where to locate the module files imported into a program. It should include the Python source library directory and the directories containing Python source code. PYTHONPATH is sometimes preset by the Python installer.